# Some mistakes when I reload "torch.nn.functioanl"?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I want to modify some functions in "torch.nn.functional", and then I use "importlib.reload" to reload the new "torch.nn.functional".But I encounter a Runtime error:function 'avg_pool2d' already has a docstring.

I am trying to do some work on excitationbp(https://github.com/greydanus/excitationbp), and there is a  operation named "eb.use_eb()"  to modify "torch.nn.functional". The functiona eb.use_eb() is for modifying the "torch.nn.linear","torch.nn.functional.conv1d" and so on.I try to modify the code including many eb.use_eb() in the utils.py.When I want to run the original "torch.nn.linear",I must run the eb.use_eb(False).But the module has loaded in the head of the file(import torch.nn.funtional). So I want to reload the module "torch.nn.funtional".
When I use the "importlib.reload", I encounter a error.

```
eb.use_eb(False,True)
importlib.reload(torch)
importlib.reload(torch.nn)
importlib.reload(torch.nn.functional) 
print("gradient_evidence:"+str(gradient_evidence))
return torch.autograd.grad(contr_h_, target_h_, grad_outputs=gradient_evidence)[0]
```

```
RuntimeError         Traceback (most recent call last)
ipython-input-15-29d0fca29882 in module()
----> 1 prob_inputs_one = eb.excitation_backprop(model, inputs, prob_outputs_one, contrastive=2)
      2 #pdb.set_trace()
      3 prob_inputs_true = eb.excitation_backprop(model, inputs, prob_outputs_true, contrastive=2)

~/code/excitationbp/excitationbp-master/excitationbp/utils.py in excitation_backprop(model, inputs, prob_outputs, contrastive, target_layer)
     75         importlib.reload(torch)
     76         importlib.reload(torch.nn)
---> 77         importlib.reload(torch.nn.functional)
     78 
     79         gradient_evidence = torch.autograd.grad(top_h_, contr_h_, grad_outputs=prob_outputs.clone())[0]

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch0.3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py in reload(module)
    164         target = module
    165         spec = module.__spec__ = _bootstrap._find_spec(name, pkgpath, target)
--> 166         _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
    167         # The module may have replaced itself in sys.modules!
    168         return sys.modules[name]

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch0.3/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _exec(spec, module)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch0.3/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch0.3/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch0.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in <module>()
    286     count_include_pad: when True, will include the zero-padding in th
    287         averaging calculation. Default: ``True``
--> 288 """)
    289 
    290 avg_pool3d = _add_docstr(torch._C._nn.avg_pool3d, r"""

RuntimeError: function 'avg_pool2d' already has a docstring
```

Comment: I am sorry, but `pytorch0.3`? :(

Comment: `pytorch0.3` is just the name of my virtual environment in Anaconda3. The original code depends on `pytorch0.3`